# Android NDK - build executable with .so extension

Tags: android, android-ndk, executable

How can I build an executable with `Android NDK` (`include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)`) but with file extension.

Here is my `Android.mk`

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ls
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ls.c

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

It works as expected, but file is without extension. If library doesn't have `.so` extension it doesn't get packed into the `apk`.

Comment: Found the following posts that might help: 1) - [Hosting an executable within Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583487/hosting-an-executable-within-android-application); 2) - [Package Android apk with additional executables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998419/package-android-apk-with-additional-executables); 3) - [How to package native commandline application in apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383552/how-to-package-native-commandline-application-in-apk).

Answer (score 1):

I did his:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ndk-build
cd ../libs
for f in $(ls .);
do
    mv $f/ls $f/libls.so
done
```

This script should be put in jni folder, and instead of calling just `ndk-build` i call this script.
Its not dynamic, name of the executable is hardcoded, but is does the job in my case.